# How to get contents of a specific html element in Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm currently trying to get a table and it's contents/formatting from wikipedia using jsoup. However when I run this code I get an error at line 29:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at project.wikiclass.main(wikiclass.java:29)

I don't know of any way to get the data. The name I am currently using does not seem to be right. The table is at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liverpool_F.C.#First-team_squad

In inspect element the outermost element needed is called `<table border="0">`.

However I cannot get the element by id using the name border. If anyone can tell me how to get this element or what it's real name is that would be helpful. The element is findable by going to the linked page and highlighting the list of names and using inspect element.

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class wikiclass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {

        // need http protocol
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liverpool_F.C.").get();

        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);

        //make html file
        StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

        // get all links
        String table = doc.getElementById("border").outerHtml();
        System.out.println(table);
        /*for (Element link : links) {

            // get the value from href attribute
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

        }*/

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have NPE because Jsoup can't find this element.

You can try this

```
 Elements table = doc.select("div#bodyContent table.infobox");
```

Then iterate for ech element and get information